# Troubleshooting Styled Media Receiver css

Tags: css, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to implement styled media receiver, but for some reason, my chromecast won't show the graphics. I get only name of my receiver on black background. Preview in cast dev console looks OK though.
The css I'm trying to use is this: https://krizan.se/styl_latest.css

What I tried and did not help:

- CORS enabled and disabled, doesn't make a difference. Left it enabled. Verified by streaming video from the server on chromecast
- I tried using both absolute and relative paths for images, no change.
- Tried using both http and https, no change either.
- The image I'm using is 1280x720, as in guidelines. Tried changing it to different sizes, no change
- Remove and register my chromecast again in dev console, no change

I spent too many hours trying to fix this, trying all combinations of above, but still can't see my graphics on my cast device. There was one question on stackoverflow with the same issue, but without answer.

Is this some kind of bug or am I doing something wrong? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to check the [documents](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver#css) here about SMR. You can customize the SMR color scheme by providing your own CSS file during registration. You can either use the default styles or provide the HTTPS URL to your CSS file. Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254684/chromecast-custom-receiver-styling) and this [issue](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/s/pontus%20holmberg/top) that file by Pontus Holmberg about chromecast for more information.

Comment: Have you looked at the receiver's logs in the chrome debugger to find out what is happening, looking for errors or such? That would be the first thing I'd do.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Can you give some more info about the chrome debugger?  What webpage are you testing on?

Comment: Read about debugging here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging

Comment: Okay so i have the debugger set up.  And i am in the console tab, but i don't see any errors. Also i noticed that the style sheets that show up in the elements tab are from `https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/0012/player.css`  The stylesheet i provided in the chromecast developer console is not showing up in the chrome debugger.

Comment: The Skin URL that i have provided is from a github repo, is that an issue?

Comment: I event tried a public google drive link but that didn't work either.

Comment: Same problem here. The preview looks fine, but no CSS styling appears on my Chromecast. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to have a valid certificate for the HTTPS connection. Also, the URL is currently returning 404 for the CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

So my problem was that url that was hosting the CSS file was not the raw CSS file.  So i used this website https://rawgit.com/ to host the CSS file.